# Навзничь и ничком

Tags: этимология

Упасть на спину — *навзничь*, упасть на живот — *ничком*. А какова этимология этих слов?

Answer (score 2):

Оба слова этимологически восходят к одному праслав. сущ. *nikъ,* nika > никъ, ника «низ». Сущ. никъ в свою очередь является производным с суф. -к-ъ (как *злак*) от того же корня *ни-* «внизу», что и в слове *низ*. Из праслав. *никъ* вследствие изменения после гласн. и (при третьем смягчении задненебных) звука **к** в **ц** возникло слово ***ниць* «лицом вниз»**, преобразовавшееся после падения слаб. **ь** и отвердения **ц** в соврем. рус. 
**ниц** «касаясь лицом земли» (ср. укр. ниць — тожд., где **и** изменился в **ы**, а **ц** сохранил мягкость; рус. диал. ницый «низкий», «склонившийся»). От сущ. *никъ* «низ, изнанка», «затылок» в рус. яз. возникла уменьш. форма **ничькъ** с суф. -ьк-ъ (чередов. к/'/ч). Твор. пад. ед. ч. этой формы **ничком** обособился в самостоятельное слово-наречие со знач. «затылком» (наверх), иначе «лицом вниз». Наречие же **навзничь** легко объяснить: упасть **на** "затылок", т.е. **на** спину. (Словари Цыганенко, Фасмера).